# Random selection of list elements

Tags: python, list, random, valueerror

Goal: print random selection of list elements, at least 1 to all, as a list-comprehension.

Attempt:

```
import random

BENEFITS = ['foo', 'bar', 'idk', 'lol']

selection = [sorted(random.sample(BENEFITS, random.randint(1, len(BENEFITS))]
print(selection)
```

Desired Output:

```
foo, idk
```

ValueError:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-407cc8d7fbfe> in <module>
----> 1 v = [[k, eval(v)] for k, v in sorted(random.sample([BENEFITS], random.randint(3, len(BENEFITS)-1)))]
      2 
      3 print(v)

~\Anaconda3\lib\random.py in sample(self, population, k)
    361         n = len(population)
    362         if not 0 <= k <= n:
--> 363             raise ValueError("Sample larger than population or is negative")
    364         result = [None] * k
    365         setsize = 21        # size of a small set minus size of an empty list

ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative
```

Please let me know if there is anything else I can add to post.

Comment: Why are you using `eval()`?

Comment: You don't need to put `[]` around `BENEFITS`. It's already a list. You're creating a new list with just a single element.

Comment: Thought it would help, I meant to remove it

Comment: `random.randint(3, len(BENEFITS)-1))` makes no sense. `len(BENEFITS)-1` is 3. So you're asking for a random int from 3 to 3, which will always be 3!

Comment: Sorry guys, I've updated my code sample that *I think* is close to the solution. I was trying many different things

Comment: What are `k` and `v`? There's no dictionary with keys and values.

Comment: The error message doesn't match the edited code.

Comment: You don't need v since you are using a list not a dictionary. Get rid of the v.

Comment: What does 1 to all mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `choices` from module `random`. Then

```
from random import choices
BENEFITS = ['foo', 'bar', 'idk', 'lol']
print(choices(BENEFITS,k=2))
```

At this way, function `choices` returns a random sample of length `k=2` from `BENEFITS`.

Comment: I believe OP wants `k` to be random, too.

Comment: this results in duplicates like [bar, bar]; not sure if it matters though, just wanted to bring it up.

Comment: That's the main difference between `choices` and `sample`, whether duplicates are allowed.

Comment: @StressedBoi69420 if you dont want repeated elements you must use 'sample' instead of 'choices', because 'choices' may returns duplicates like said rv.kvetch

Answer (score 0):

I had many different errors, when attempting to place this in either a dictionary or as a list-comprehension.

Minimal Code Answer:

```
import random

BENEFITS = ['foo', 'bar', 'idk', 'lol']

selection = sorted(random.sample(BENEFITS, random.randint(1, len(BENEFITS))))
print(selection)
```

Comment: So list comprehension wasn't a requirement of the exercise?

Comment: Sorry man, I made the incorrect assumption that it needed to be, based on two reasons: I wanted a one-line code, and the object returned to be a list. Thankfully, `sorted()` in of itself does both for me.